# How do I find the Wiggler segment in the Bafflewood?

Tags: paper-mario-sticker-star

I'm stuck on my second visit to the Bafflewood.  A Toad near the entrance says that something round and yellow has been by, but I can't find anything new in this level.  I keep using the "good" paths that I marked with stickers the first time through this level, but I can't find the Wiggler segment.  Where is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow "correct" path until you find a poison pool with 2 Sniff-its in it. Take the **right** exit from there, go right again and there is the Wiggler segment.

Comment: Was there a way to figure this out other than trial and error (or searching online)?